# Send a WFS GET request using lat lng information only to get data that are bound with that layer

Tags: geoserver, wfs

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&TRANSPARENT=true&VERSION=1.1.1&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=90.28375625610352%2C23.76602241357594%2C90.5153274536133%2C23.923031699083083&HEIGHT=1000&WIDTH=1349&LAYERS=mouza%3Amouza&QUERY_LAYERS=mouza%3Amouza&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&X=504&Y=357'
```

this is what I am sending right now and the response  is :

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "mouza.275340",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                90.3710619,
                23.86652544
            ]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {
            "Type": "Plot",
            "M_ward": "Harirampur Union",
            "M_U_P_CC": "Harirampur Union",
        }
    }
],
"totalFeatures": "unknown",
"numberReturned": 1,
"timeStamp": "2022-06-03T09:37:40.655Z",
"crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
    }
}
```

}

How can I send a GET request with layer name and lat/lng that will return a `FeatureCollection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make a [WFS](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/index.html) request with a [CQL filter](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/vendor.html#cql-filters) to limit the features returned.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?REQUEST=GetFeature&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&FORMAT=application/json&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&TYPENAMEs=mouza:Amouza&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS%28the_geom%2CPOINT%28-74.817265%2040.5296504%29%29'
```